# Get value of input field with a checkbox and put them in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I see that this question has been marked as "duplicate", which is not correct in my opinion. The question is about how to *copy* a text from the "textbox" with the checkbox, *not* how to change this text in the textbox.

In my example, the "textbox" is empty , and must be filled in by the user, and the checkbox has to copy what has been written in the textbox (type="checkbox" value=written-text-on-specific-textbox)

---

When the checkbox is checked, I need it to take the text written in the `<input type="text" id="profile">` and with this text, create a URL

```js
nickname = $('#profile').val();
if (nickname != '') {
  text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/" + nickname + "/'>Profile</a>\n";
}

nickname = $('#gallery').val();
if (nickname != '') {
  text += "<a href='https://web.com/profile/gallery/" + nickname + "/'>Gallery</a>\n";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://videochatencasa.com/buton/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" placeholder="your username" id="profile" required>

<br>

<input type="checkbox" id="gallery" name="chatprof2" value="profile">
```

Expected result:

Suppose the username written in the text box, HANNA, and the checkbox, is checked.
In the HTML. these two links should be generated.

```
<a href='https://web.com/profile/HANNA'>Profile</a>
<a href='https://web.com/profile/gallery/hanna'>Gallery</a>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I see that this question has been marked as "duplicate", which is NOT true. The question is about how to COPY a text from the "textbox" with the checkbox, NOT how to change this text.
In my example, the "textbox" is EMPTY, and must be filled in by the user, and the checkbox has to COPY what has been WRITTEN in the textbox (value=written-text-on-specific-textbox)